# Suitable CAN bus connector

Tags: can

I am searching for suitable CAN bus connector for i.MX nxp ultralite eval board. Is there any suitable connector for it?

Comment: what's an `i.MX nxp ultralite eval board`? ... does it have a connector?

Comment: Welcome. Please add links to the description and data sheets for the specific evaluation board you are using. Don't make us have to search for them and guess which one you are using, if there are alternatives.

Comment: To the VTCer: shopping questions aren't allowed but, by convention, connector identification questions are.

Comment: I. MX6Ultralite eval kit

Comment: @GrahamNye - Hi, Re: "*shopping questions aren't allowed but, by convention, connector identification questions are*" - True, except that as currently written, unfortunately this is not a valid [identification question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines) :( It doesn't include a photo of the component whose identification is being requested. Due to the lack of a photo (or link to the details of the OP's board - despite your request for that), I'm unsure if this is a question about an *existing* connector or something else...

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for the reference, bookmarked.

Answer (score 2):

[CiA 106](https://www.can-cia.org/can-knowledge/can/cia106/) has an extensive list of recommended connectors/pin assignments for Classical CAN, CAN FD and CAN XL interfaces.

Some common ones include:

*D-SUB 9-pin connector*

[image]

[image]

*RJ10 connector*

[image]

[image]

*RJ45 connector*

[image]

[image]

---

An overview of all connector recommendations (CiA 106, Version 1.1.0):

- D-SUB 9-pin connector
- RJ10 connector
- RJ45 connector
- Multi-pole connector
- Open-style connector
- 5-pin 7/8” connector
- 5-pin M12 connector
- 5-pin M8 connector
- Han-Quintax connector
- 7-pin round connector
- 8-pin round connector
- 9-pin round connector
- 10-pin round connector
- Mini-snap 10-pin round connector
- 12-pin round flange connector
- 9-pin flange round T-connector with ID-switch
- Han-Brid CU connector
- IEEE1394/Firewire connector with shielding
- Mini-Fit Jr. connector
- Micro-Fit 3.0 connector
- (Automotive) 7-pin socket connector
- (Automotive) 9-pin socket connector
- 18-pin VDA interface connector
- 2-pin power connector
- Header 10-pin plug connector
- D-SUB 15-pin connector
- 8-pin Ampseal connector (redundant CAN networks)
- 9-pin Deutsch HD10-9 connector
- 9-pin breakaway connector
- 4-pin Isobus connector
- Truck/trailer connector
- 32-pin four-part connector
- 16-pin OBD-II connector
- DroneCAN micro connector
- CANaerospace D38999/20FA35PN connector
- CANaerospace D38999/20FB35PN connector

You'll have to sign up and download the document.